# My python graph is not popping up through ubuntu despite already downloading all the necessary tools

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, plot

I am trying to test a simple graph program from Greeks for Greeks that involved python as you see here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-plotting-in-python-set-1/. But despite downloading everything that I need the graph is not popping up through my ubuntu. Can someone help me to fix this problem because I have been looking at resources and couldn't find anything that has truly helped me to fix this problem so far?

```
# Start of the code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
# line 1 points
x1 = [1,2,3]
y1 = [2,4,1]
# plotting the line 1 points 
plt.plot(x1, y1, label = "line 1")
  
# line 2 points
x2 = [1,2,3]
y2 = [4,1,3]
# plotting the line 2 points 
plt.plot(x2, y2, label = "line 2")
  
# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('Two lines on same graph!')
  
# show a legend on the plot
plt.legend()
  
# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly.  Therefore, the issue is in the way you are running it.  How, SPECIFICALLY, are you running this?

Comment: @TimRoberts I am running it through Ubuntu but the problem is the graph is not popping up and no resources on the web have given me any solution. Like I would hit python3 Graph.py and nothing shows up.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaElendu are you running this through WSL, or are you booted into an Ubuntu machine?

Comment: @TakeThat101 I running it through an ubuntu terminal

Comment: Are you doing this on a local desktop, or are you ssh-ing in?  I literally just ran this on an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and it was fine, but it won't work over ssh unless you do X forwarding.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you on elaborate on the two things you said because I don't know what you mean by ssh-ing? All I can confidently say is that I been running on the Ubuntu for Windows terminal on my own laptop.

Comment: See, that's the first time you mentioned Windows, and that's the critical piece of information.  So, you ARE running WSL (Windows Subsystem for LInux).  WSL 1 does not do graphics applications at all, and WSL 2 only JUST got support, in Windows 11 build 22000.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Comment: @TimRoberts So you are saying I need to upgrade WSL to WSL 2 in order for my graphs to actually pop up?

Comment: Well, Python is exactly the same on WIndows and Linux, so why don't you just run this in a Windows command shell?  WSL isn't buying you anything.  You would have you upgrade your Windows as well as WSL.  It's not worth the trouble.